# How to use Dart 3 Pattern Matching to match an element that is not the first nor the last element of a list?

Tags: flutter, dart, pattern-matching, dart3, dart-pattern-matching

I am working on a Dart project and I'm trying to use pattern matching to match an element that is not the first nor the last element of a list. However, I haven't been able to figure out the correct syntax or approach to achieve this.

Let's say I have the following three lists:

`[{"key1": true}, {"key2":true}, {"key3": true}] [{"key2": true}, {"key1": true}, {"key3":true}] [{"key1":true},{"key3": true}, {"key2": true}]`

In each of these lists, I want to match the element {"key2":true} regardless of its position in the list.

I've tried using pattern matching with the ... rest operator, but unfortunately, it doesn't support having two rest elements in the pattern. For example, I cannot write [..., {"key2":true}, ...] to match the desired element.

Is there a way to achieve this using Dart's pattern matching feature? If so, what would be the correct syntax or approach to match an element that is not the first nor the last element of a list?

[..., {"key2":true}, ...] -> gives me "At most one rest element is allowed in a list or map pattern"

Comment: Are the lists of varying length or can we assume all of the lists are length 3? Because if they are all length 3 you can use wildcards instead of rest elements.

Comment: If not, you could try to loop through the list and use an [if-case](https://dart.dev/language/branches#if-case) to match against what you are looking for.

Comment: Another option could be to do it recursively. You would have a base case for empty list, a case where you check if the first element is what you are looking for, and in the 3rd case you recursively call the function on the rest of the list.

Comment: The length is not always 3, it can vary. I have solved it in another way (I can share it here), but my point is that, in my opinion, Dart 3 Patterns should support this case.

Comment: You're welcome to suggest this as a feature [here](https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues) if you think dart should support this. But this is not supported by pattern matching in any programming language I can think of. The documentation for [C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/patterns#list-patterns), and [Rust](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/patterns.html#rest-patterns), also say you are limited to one rest pattern in your list/array as a few examples.

Comment: You cannot have a "wildcard" like that in a list match. Only one "..." is permitted.  This ensures that the pattern can be matched quickly in one try, and doesn't require iteration.

Answer (score -1):

how about something like this?

```
void main() {
  List<Map<String, bool>> list1 = [
    {"key1": true},
    {"key2": true},
    {"key3": true}
  ];

  List<Map<String, bool>> list2 = [
    {"key2": true},
    {"key1": true},
    {"key3": true}
  ];

  List<Map<String, bool>> list3 = [
    {"key1": true},
    {"key3": true},
    {"key2": true}
  ];

  for (var list in [list1, list2, list3]) {
    if (list.length >= 3) {
      if (list[1]["key2"] == true) {
        print("Matched in list: $list");
      }
    }
  }
}
```

you cant specify a pattern for an element that is not the first or the last element of a list using the rest operator

you can do what you want by combining multiple pattenr matching conditions

Comment: *you cant specify a pattern for an element that is not the first or the last element of a list using the rest operator* is not true.  `[_, _, int foo, ...]` matches an `int foo` as the *third* element.

Comment: What exactly this answer has to do with Dart 3 and pattern matching? Downvoted